# Program goes into infinite loop when I input "9+"

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void check_positive () {
    cout << "Number given must be positive. Please try again." << endl;
}

int main() {
    int pesos, interest, compound, year;
    do {
        cout << "How many pesos did you deposit? ";
        cin >> pesos;
        if (pesos <= 0) {
            check_positive();
    }
    } while (pesos <= 0);
    do {
        cout << "What is the interest? ";
        cin >> interest;
        if (interest <= 0) {
            check_positive();
        }
    } while (interest <= 0);
}
```

Whenever I run this code and enter "9+" as the input during the first loop, the first loop ends but then goes into an infinite loop immediately after the second loop starts. Why does this happen?

Comment: Because you never check whether your input ooeration succeeds.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Be as specific as you can. What code do you think handles this case and how do you think it handles it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521320/why-do-i-get-an-infinite-loop-if-i-enter-a-letter-rather-than-a-number
already discussed here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You entered characters `9+` that are not a number, and tried to load them into an integer variable `int pesos` which can only accept numbers. Cin couldn't convert `9+` to a number and so it entered fail state which you can check by changing your first loop like so:

```
do {
    cout << "How many pesos did you deposit? ";
    cin >> pesos;

    if (cin.fail()) {
        cout << "You didn't enter a number!";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (pesos <= 0) {
        check_positive();
}
```

be wary that you can also have the same problem in the second loop and thus you need to check `cin.fail()` again there

For additional reading: [ios::fail() reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/fail/)

Comment: But why didn't the first loop repeat instead of the second loop since the variable "pesos" was the one that had the unacceptable value?

Comment: I think it depends on the implementation of cin, but probably because cin read `9` and put it into pesos variable, and then got into fail state due to `+`, since now `pesos > 0` it exits the first loop. And when you tried to use cin in failed state to read into `int interest` it returns immediately without reading any input.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you for all the help :)