# How to stop an infinite loop due to invalid input C++

Tags: c++, do-while

So I want to accept two inputs, a string and an int, and when the user enters "end" to exit out of the loop.
My problem is when "end" is entered that it gets stuck in a loop, since (I'm assuming) it is expecting two inputs when the user only types in one.
I've done some research and found stuff on discarding the input and resetting it with `cin.ignore()` and `cin.clear()`, however, these seem to only apply when accepting a single input, where as I'm asking for two separate inputs on one line, and it doesn't seem to work.
What my code is doing is basically asking for a list of things (name value), storing it in an array in a class, and is capped at 10 items. So, when "end" in entered, it only needs to exit the while loop. Everything else seems to work fine, i.e. when I enter 10 items it exits the loop and the rest of the code executes like it should. So there just seems to be a problem when typing in 'end'. (p.s. a is a string and b in an int type).
The section of code is:

```
do {

    cout << "Enter the item and value (enter 'end' to stop): ";
    cin >> a >> b;

    items1.set_name(a, i);
    items1.set_price(b, i);

    i++;

}  while ( i < 10 && a != "end" );
```

This seems like it should be very simple, and I'm sorry if its a stupid question, but I can't figure it out hahah.
Thanks in advance for helping me out.

Comment: What are the types of `a` and `b`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get an infinite loop if I enter a letter rather than a number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521320/why-do-i-get-an-infinite-loop-if-i-enter-a-letter-rather-than-a-number)

Comment: You do not test the stream state after input. Have a final `ìf(cin)` before processing the data.

Comment: It doesn't get stuck in a loop, it is waiting for the second input before proceeding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to test the value of `a` BEFORE proceeding to read `b`; something like this:

```
cin >> a;
if(a == "end")
  break;
cin >> b;
```

Comment: It worked, and so simple too, hah. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

To get out of the loop, use

```
if (a == "end" || b == "end") break;
```