# Why do I get an infinite loop when I press a letter? How do I change for error checking?

Tags: c++, error-handling, error-checking

Why do I get an infinite loop when I press a letter? How do I prevent my code from going into an infinite loop when error checking?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number;
    cout << "Enter a number in the range 1-100: ";
    cin >> number;

    while (number > 1 || number < 100)
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Enter a value in the range 1-100: ";
        cin >> number;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm to lazy to find a good duplicate (there are quite a few here on stackoverflow.com, and even more out on the wider Internet) ,but the gist of the problem is that when the input operator can't parse the input as a number, it leaves the input in the buffer, it doesn't remove anything. So each time in the loop it will read the same input over and over again. Read about [the `ignore` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) to help you.

Comment: Think about what the condition in the while statement is doing.

Comment: Also note that if you are using an older compiler or building in pre-C++11 mode, then you will have *undefined behavior* because `number` will not be modified on illegal input. And since it's not initialize then it will have an *indeterminate* value and the comparison in the loop will then give you the UB.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks!

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because std::cin is type safe, it knows that a letter is not a valid input for "int number". It raises an error flag in std::cin and any subsequent operation will fail and return immediately.

You'll need to check the error state and clear any error flag(s) before you can proceed.

See existing post [Why do I get an infinite loop if I enter a letter rather than a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521320/why-do-i-get-an-infinite-loop-if-i-enter-a-letter-rather-than-a-number)

Comment: Thanks! @Tanguy Fautré

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot y'all. I ended up going with this one.

```
while (!(cin >> number)) 
{ 
   cout << "ERROR: Enter a value in the range 1-100: "; 

   //to clear input stream
   cin.clear();   

   //to discard previous input
   cin.ignore(1200, '\n'); 

   cin >> number; 
}
```