# Entering specific character into while loop

Tags: c++

I am writing a code for class that asks the user to input a size that is an odd number equal to or greater than `7`. I have been able to make that part of my code work successfully. However, the next part consists of asking the user to enter a specific letter, in this case `'c'`. If they do not enter `'c'` then the loop should ask them to input another character. Whenever I run this code, it is creating an infinite loop whether I enter `'c'` or another letter. I think my expression in my second `while` loop is incorrect, but I haven't been able to find a lot of information regarding this that could help me.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int s, l;

    cout << "Welcome to the letter printer." << endl;
    cout << "Enter the size: " << endl;
    cin >> s;
    while (s < 7 || s%2==0 || s<0)
    {
        cout << "Invalid size. Enter the size again: " << endl;
        cin >> s;
    }

    cout << "Enter the letter: " << endl;
    cin >> l;
    while (l != 'c')
    {
        cout << "Invalid letter. Enter the letter again: " << endl;
        cin >> l;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look at the type of `l`.  is it a character type?

Comment: Use a debugger and examine what is happening to the value of `l` in the loop and the conditional. Your instincts are good and by using the tools to see what's happening you will fix this easily.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get an infinite loop if I enter a letter rather than a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521320/why-do-i-get-an-infinite-loop-if-i-enter-a-letter-rather-than-a-number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you are getting char for int variable

wrong:

```
int s, l;
```

right one:

```
int s;
char l;
```

what is why it goes on infinite loop in second while

explanation for infinite loop

> This is how basic_istream works. In your case when cin >> l gets
>   wrong input - failbit is set and cin is not cleared. So next time it
>   will be the same wrong input. To handle this correctly you can add
>   check for correct input and clear&ignore cin in case of wrong input.

incorporated from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521320/why-do-i-get-an-infinite-loop-if-i-enter-a-letter-rather-than-a-number/19521636#19521636)

Comment: But why does the program not stop at `cin >> l` until the user enters something? How does that relate to the type of `l`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 it was explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521320/why-do-i-get-an-infinite-loop-if-i-enter-a-letter-rather-than-a-number/19521636#19521636)